# MS project Interop: Get task after change

Tags: c#, events, vsto, ms-project

I am working with MS project(2007) interop in a C# VSTO addin. I want to check the new task finish date whenever user changes the task.

I am using `Application.ProjectBeforeTaskChange` to monitor task changes. but it only gives task before the change and the value that is directly changing. I want task after change.

For example if i change task duration, this event only tells me that duration is changing(and the new duration). At the same time `Task.Finish` is also changing(which i am interested at) but the event does not give me the new `Task.Finish`.

Is there any way to get the task after task changing finished?(I dont want to calculate finish time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very elegant, but you could consider adding the task to a queue and performing your processing in a separate thread once a suitable short delay has elapsed. That way you'll be able to reload the task and pick up the modified value.

Comment: that's very close to what i did finally. With every change event i applied the change myself(instead of waiting for it to be automatically applied) consequently, other values changed and i was able to use them.(no queue, no separate thread, no delay... but a lot messier)